# Random and Repeated in SPSS mixed model

Tags: mixed-model, spss, repeated-measures, multilevel-analysis, random-effects-model

I have a data set with 4 time points and around 200 'subjects' (in my case local authorities). I want to look at predictors of my dependent variable and changes over time in my dependent variable.

I want to do a multi-level model using the MIXED command in SPSS.  I know I need to use the /REPEATED subcommand, because I want to specify an auto-regressive covariance matrix (AR1).  My question is do I also need to use the /RANDOM subcommand too?

In effect which of these two syntaxes is correct (where Xs are my predictors, and LA is local authority code):

MIXED LifeSat WITH Xs 
  /FIXED= Xs | SSTYPE(3) 
  /METHOD=ML 
  /PRINT=G SOLUTION TESTCOV 
  /REPEATED=Year | SUBJECT(LA) COVTYPE(AR1).

Or would it be?

MIXED LifeSat WITH Xs 
  /FIXED= Xs | SSTYPE(3) 
  /METHOD=ML 
  /PRINT=G SOLUTION TESTCOV 
 /RANDOM=Intercept| SUBJECT(LA)
 /REPEATED=Year | SUBJECT(LA) COVTYPE(AR1).

Seems a basic question, but I can't find an answer anywhere!

Thanks
Saamah

Comment: Did you find the answer? Care to share? BTW, I think the correct one is the second one.